# How to modify the properties of item inside Dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary, and I want to modify the property of an item inside the dictionary, how to achieve this? Can I use foreach to modify the item's properties? I has surveyed some posts, they said the reference obtained from foreach is readonly, which can not be modified.

```
class MyClass
{
   public int propA { get; set; }
   public string propB { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
   private Dictionary<int, List<MyClass>> mItemMap;

   ....
   public void QueryAndModify() {
      // My original thought, find what i want by foreach
      foreach(KeyValuePair<int, List<MyClass>> kvp in mItemMap) {
          foreach(MyClass item in kvp.Value) {
            // Can I modify the propB of item by this way ?
            if (item.propA == 3) {
                item.propB = "I got you.";
            }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try that code ? It seems good to me...

Comment: you can also do the same in LINQ

Comment: I don't know how to use LINQ at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can modify items in-place.

Comment: Dude.... modifying an item == modifying its properties. OK, just to totally complete the answer then: you can also replace items in-place.

Comment: Sorry, I misread you answer... I read "No, you can't" instead of "can"... then ignore my previous comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can modify the values, but cannot remove items from the dictionary from inside the foreach loop.

Comment: That is right, if you foreach over a collection, you cannot modify the collection -- i.e., add/remove/replace items.

Comment: So, when I foreach over a dictionary collection, can I modify the Key and Value of KeyPairValue? Or I can only modify the Value of KeyPairValue?

Comment: You'd only modify the Value, if you change the key you're changing the reference. You shouldn't have a problem with the code you've supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is a collection of REFERENCES to instances of MyClass. Modifying properties of the instance does not modify the reference that is stored in the dictionary.

While iterating over the collection you can't modify the COLLECTION ( add,remove items from it). You can modify the instances that the references in the collection are pointing to.

I would recommand you get a good C# book and understand values and references before proceeding.

Comment: I have no time to read a good C# book now, the dead line of project is approaching. I should not curse my boss here ... so...

Comment: The thing is that after you truly understand how C# works you will realize why it's a great language for mainstream. If you have c/c++ background just imagine that all references are pointers or better yet smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As Roy said, you can.

Consider also restructuring your code:

```
public void QueryAndModify()
{
   foreach( List<MyClass> list in mItemMap.Values )
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

hth

Mario